# select into with a constraint id postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table `images`

```
id,image,download,type
1,url1,0,'extra'
2,url2,0,'main'
3,url3,1,'extra'
```

I am copying some of it's data for testing purposes into `temp1` and giving the `id` "p_key" using

`select * into temp1 from images where download=0 order by id offset 0 limit 1000000;`
then

```
alter table temp1 add constraint temp1_pk primary key (id);
```

is there a way of combining the two commands into 1 command?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by having them be one command? Perhaps what you want is to run them both in one transaction?

Comment: As a side note: the `select .. into new_table` syntax is discouraged in favor of the standard compliant `create new_table as select ...` - but no, you can't do it in one step.

Comment: @BlueStar yes you can think of it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to combine these two statements into one, and from a performance perspective it is preferrable to add the constraint *after* you insert the data.

So execute both statements in a single transaction, and you will have all the benefits of combining the statements:

```
BEGIN;
/* your statements */
COMMIT;
```